# How to wait for api call on js export?

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, async-await

I have a Vue app where I initialize my firestore app. My code looks like the following:

```
if (firebase.apps.length) {
  firebase.app()
} else {
  firebase.initializeApp(config)
}
export const Firestore = firebase.firestore()
export const Auth = firebase.auth()
```

Now I would like to bring the config file from some API. Which mean, instead of doing
firebase.initializeApp(config)
I would like to do something like:

```
axios.get('https://.../config.json', {})
    .then(async ({ data }) => {
      firebase.initializeApp(data)
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log('error', err)
    })
```

But my exports will have to wait till I get the response from the API and init the app.

How can I make the exports wait with async/await or any other pattern?

Answer (score 1):

You can just do:

```
export const initialize = () => {
 try {
   return axios.get('https://.../config.json', {})
    } catch(err) {
      console.log('error', err)
    }
  }
```

And then in another js file, you can first import it and then do the following:

```
initialize().then(data => {
firebase.initializeApp(data)
firebase.firestore()
}).catch((err) => {
    console.log(err);
});
```

There is no point to export `firebase.firestore()`, since you are going to be calling it in every js file if you want to use firestore.

The only method that you really need to export is `firebase.initializeApp(data)` which you can add it inside the method `initialize()` and return it

Comment: Hi, The idea is that I want firebase.firestore() and firebase.auth() to run only once and not call it every time I want to use it. I can't export firebase.initializeApp(data) from initialize(), since export statement can't be inside a function or a callback